# How do I set up USB security key based authentication?

Tags: usb, security, login, usb-drive, lock-screen

Is it possible to get Ubuntu to lock and unlock itself, if a particular USB stick is attached?

For example; I sit down at my laptop; I plug the USB stick in and the system unlocks and presents itself.

I take the USB stick out, and the system locks and cannot be unlocked without that particular USB stick.

Is there any way to do this, my friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any products (like Predator for Windows) but I have seen this solution which appears to work:

Use a script to loop&sleep filtering  to grep for info specific to your USB stick. When you get a match, kill the screensaver.

Be sure to have the sleep timer a LOT shorter when the USB is removed than when the USB is inserted.

When you are away (USB removed) all your machine has to do is fanatically cycle through lsusb looking for your return (USB inserted).

EDIT:
A working example of this to get you on your way can be found at http://www.techienote.com/2011/03/lock-unlock-ubuntu-desktop-using-usb-drive.html

Comment: Yuck, it would be better to have udev trigger an event on USB insertion/removal that would read someone off the key for verification.

Comment: Thank you, my friend! Though I have to say, I was rather hoping there was a simpler, easier program for it... Still, there's nothing like being baptised by fire when it comes to cron :P

Answer (score 0):

[Pamusb](https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb) is a much easier solution:

> pam_usb provides hardware authentication for Linux using ordinary USB Flash Drives.
> It works with any application supporting PAM, such as su and login managers (GDM, KDM).

- [Official Getting Started guide](https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb/wiki/Getting-Started)
- [Debian wiki guide on pamusb](https://wiki.debian.org/pamusb)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Andrea Luzzardi's main project seems unmaintained (see about on GH), [pamusb.org](https://www.pamusb.org/) point to deprecated links, and `libpam-usb`/`pamusb-tools` are only available through PPA