# Replace Ubuntu login screen and password based login

Tags: 16.04, login, security

I am trying to poke around Linux environment a bit and have started off with smaller scripts doing this and that. Now I want to do some major stuff but couldn't find out anywhere how to.

- What I want to do is to modify/replace Ubuntu login screen. Not just the wallpaper/UI childish stuff but actually poke around its code. Not sure if one can do it but is it possible? Can anyone point me in right direction?
- I also want to replace password security with something like a hardware encrypted USB key or may be something bio-metric.

I just want to be pointed in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check these posts for answers : http://askubuntu.com/questions/193/how-can-i-change-the-login-screen-theme-in-gdm ,  http://askubuntu.com/questions/143192/how-can-i-replace-lightdm-with-mdm

Comment: okay so all these tell me about how I can change theme and stuff. But that is not what I want. I need to bypass Ubuntu's authentication mechanism and replace it with my own.

Comment: Check these links : https://linuxconfig.org/linux-authentication-login-with-usb-device , http://askubuntu.com/questions/62535/how-do-i-set-up-usb-security-key-based-authentication